# Smoking Motor Drive parts

Tags: mosfet

[image]I have the attached schematic.  It seems to work and do what it needs to do, but it only works a few times then smokes the P channel mosfet (fqp27p06). It actually works for a bit before it smokes.

I have a 12v motor that is ran from a GPIO pin to turn on the 12v system.  The P channel mosfet suppose to help with the active braking, which does seem to work (a few times).  I am very new to this.  Come someone tell me what I should add to quit smoking parts?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAjhCb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the motor actually has two limit sensors attached to it.  When the sensor gets hit by the motor flag, it turns the 5v off on the motor and the circuit helps stop the flag within the sensor.  the motor is then turned back on and the cycle starts again.

Comment: Doesn't that info belong in the question rather than in the comments? There's an edit link under your question. What do you mean by a flag?

Comment: What is the DCR of the motor and total kinetic energy when brake activated?

Comment: Your schematic is upside down.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, for PWM operation, do not use a 1N4001 diode for flyback protection. It's not fast enough.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I do believe you, but can you please tell me [where in the datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf) I can find that information? Is it "Fig. 3"? Or "Fig. 6"? Or is it simply experience? - I know I'd use first use a schottky or secondly a PIN diode for this setup.

Comment: @HarrySvensson - Sorry, but the information is, if you will, background. The key is the term "rectifier". As a general rule, rectifiers have very slow response (compared to fast and ultra-fast diodes) and this refers to turn-on time. Slow turn-on time allows dV/dt to produce large, nasty spikes before the diode actually clamps the voltage. Rectifiers are intended for low-frequency operation, and as such their turn-on times are simply not specified. The general rule of thumb is that, if the diode is not specified as high-speed, don't use it for PWM clamping.

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNFneC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawing in the conventional schematic layout (positive rail on top, ground on bottom with current generally flowing from top to bottom) aids comprehension.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Extract from the [FQP27P06](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP27P06.pdf) datasheet.*

Note that this device will turn on when the gate is about 3 V below the drain voltage. With a max of only 5 V available on the drain (from the GPIO) the transistor can never turn off. When M3 turns on you get "shoot-through" from the 12 V supply to ground and the high currents are destroying your MOSFETs.

Notice how much more easy it is to visualise the voltages and shoot-through when the circuit is drawn correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that your PFET is ever being turned OFF which may be the cause of your FET smoking. Looking at the your PFET [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP27P06.pdf), the gate-to-source (VGS) turn ON range is -2->-4V. Your circuit never provides a voltage difference of the source (12V) to your gate (5V or 0V) in which the gate would be OFF.

```
GPIO pin = 5V: Vgs = 5V - 12V = -7V 
GPIO pin = 0V: Vgs = 0V - 12V = -12V
```

Take a look at figure 2 in the datasheet. You will notice that the drain current will always be at its maximum given the above conditions. You need to either lower your drain voltage of 12V, or raise your GPIO voltage so that you can properly turn OFF your PFET.

Your NFET could also be replaced with a more suitable FET. [Look at its datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FQP30N06L-1009543.pdf), particularly figure 2. At 5V, the maximum drain current is not achieved.

The FETs you have chosen have internal diodes that help protect it from the quick shutoff current. The 1N4001 is much too slow to cause any noticeable difference in the circuit operation since the other diodes will react faster. It won't hurt to place a beefier fast-acting one in its place though.

Be sure to place some small decoupling capacitors next to your FETs drain-to-source pins as well as across the motor itself. Placing a large capacitor next to the power source is advisable as well.

Your circuit is also drawn a bit awkward. Try placing the voltage sources highest in the schematic and the ground terminals lowest. Essentially, you should mirror your circuit over the x-axis in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

> I am very new to this. Can someone tell me what I should add to quit
>   smoking parts?

The first modification that came to mind (keeping your basic concept in place) was to add a BJT, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAh4qL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is just a general topology and it does require some design. For example, I might "choose" to assume my I/O pin could easily handle \$4\:\text{mA}\$ and therefore size \$R_3=\frac{12\:\text{V}-5\:\text{V}-1\:\text{V}}{4\:\text{mA}}=1.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_4=\frac{5\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}-200\:\text{mV}}{4\:\text{mA}}\approx 1.0\:\text{k}\Omega\$. \$R_5\$ is there to snub oscillations and should be well less than \$R_5\le\frac{150\:\text{mV}}{40\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 3.3\:\text{k}\Omega\$. In this case, I'd probably select a stiffer value of \$R_5= 470\:\Omega\$. \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are there for several reasons and you should include space for them, even if you decide to use a zero-Ohm short instead of a resistor. While non-zero values can slow down the transition, they also can reduce EMI, reduce the current spikes, and perhaps even cope with long-wire inductances and snub oscillation tendencies. (Shortly, you'll see yet another reason to keep them.)

The output is single-ended, so you can hook up the other end of the motor to either rail, \$12\:\text{V}\$ or ground, depending on what active sense you want your I/O pin.

However, the above circuit will almost certainly have some shoot-through -- more of it on one side of your ON/OFF transition than the other, probably. There are no provisions here for creating any dead-time. You could consider using two I/O pins for that, if desired. But the circuit would then need to be quite a bit different, too.

It also completely lacks any current limiting of the shoot-through or for use with the motor.

---

So here's something to provide current limiting:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flxYmF.png)</sup>

Now, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ become important as they allow the current limiting circuit additions to do their job.

\$R_6\$ and \$R_7\$ would be sized according to whatever current-limit you choose to apply. (In general, estimate about one diode drop of voltage across the resistors when the current-limiting behavior kicks in.) Since one side is being used to activate the motor and the other side is being used for braking action, you might choose different current limits rather than having them both identically sized.

Just some thoughts for now.

---

There are half-bridge motor driver circuits in TO-220 packaging, though. For example, the [UC2950T](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slus280a/slus280a.pdf) provides up to \$4\:\text{A}\$ sink or source, with independent controls for each, in a 5-pin TO-220 package. (It includes it's own internal down-regulation to \$5\:\text{V}\$ for similar signalling levels.) That's only one of many choices available.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation.  I greatly appreciate you reading where I am very new to this and I am trying to learn. The very first comment I had was I didn't draw my schematic correctly with absolutely no input.  Thank you so much for actually reading my post instead of just looking at the picture.  As far as motor information, I'm trying to upload the information plate on the motor. I may have to add it to the original post during an edit as I don't see an area to upload during a comment.

Comment: The picture belongs in the question and not in the comments so that all of the information required to answer is in one place. The restriction is deliberate.

Comment: @jonk , could I get your email? I would like to discuss this in detail.

Comment: @mScientist Go [here](http://www.infinitefactors.org/jonk/patch.html) and find my email at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be under-designed. The Motor has a *TBD* DCR (to be determined DC resistance) spec and the inertial kinetic energy is TBD, therefore, the amount of energy that must be dumped depends on RdsOn and the time to absorb the kinetic energy in the winding and switch loss.

If NFET RdsOn is 0.045Ω approx and PFET maybe 50% higher ( est.)  then the power consumed in the FET for braking is much higher as the NFET has much more time to build up kinetic energy while the brake shorts out all motors back EMF with the kinetic energy now the driving force. \$Pd=12V^2/(DCR+R_{dsO_n})\$ for some duration determined by Force, mass and deacceleration . The 12V BEMF of 12V drops with speed to 0. This can be simplified but, not at this moment.

Unless there is current limiting with external brake dummy load of X milliOhms or a PFET rated for 10x the motor rated current resulting in an RdsOn much lower than the NFET that acts as a low side switch to drive the motor over a longer period of time, the PFET will always get hotter.

Of course, heat increases the RdsON and this can lead to thermal runaway in a brake FET. *pfft.* THus adequate power dissipation and thermal resistance calculations are needed to ensure it does not overheat.

Without any details requested, for Kinetic energy, motor DCR and Rja thermal resistance, *no design can be done properly.*

Naturally, there must be deadtime and duty factor considered in the rep. rate of these alternate seeks and perhaps temperature sensors to protect the design from failure ( and smoking parts )

p.s. Cn you learn to draw like the rest of the world with Positive Voltage supplies above 0V.